# A formula to find the organs's value from $1$ to $100$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We have a variable named **NUMBER**

This variable, can hold ANY number from $1$ to $100$.

Let's mark that number as $X$.

**We know that**:

$x(1) = 1000$ Coins
$x(100) = 250$ Coins

I need to write down a formula that will automatically find the coins amount of the variable $x$ (NUMBER).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many choices:  One approach is $$\begin {cases} x(NUMBER)=1000 & x \neq 100 \\x(NUMBER)=250 & x=100 \end {cases}$$ which is probably not what you are thinking.  You need to specify better what you want.  Probably what you are thinking is $$x(NUMBER)=1000-\frac {750}{99}(NUMBER-1)$$ which is a straight line

Comment: I've this answer from a different site: (1000 - 250) / 100 = 7.5 ==> 250 + (750 - (NUMBER * 7.5)) = Number's coins value Do you know what he did there?

Comment: @David:  the thinking is like my second.  It missed that there are $99$ gaps, not $100$ because you are counting from $1$, not $0$.  I accounted for the fact that you are counting from $1$ with the $99$ and the $-1$.  Plug $1$ into that formula and you get $992.5$

Comment: Oh... now I get it. Thanks a lot mate, there we go.